# Изменение структуры таблицы без потери данных

Tags: mysql

Подскадите пожалуйста какие способы решения данной задачи есть.Я выдаю юзеру лицензию благодаря которой юзер обладает всем функционалом для работы в системе.После того как я удаляю юзера я хочу сохранить как архив все данны об его работе  системе.Первое что пришло в голову это делать запрос к таблице с данными о действиях юзера, и на основе запроса создавть новую таблицу архив,но проблема в том что если в таблице с данными добавить или изменить какое то поле,то таблица архив уже не функционирует то есть структура у нее ужк другая и данные не заносятся.Как быть постоянно пересоздавпть таблицу или есть вариант получше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте поле в таблицу с пользователями, которое будет определять его логическое удаление. Ничего пересоздавать будет не нужно. Во всех запросах нужно будет учитывать статус этого поля.

Comment: Ага то есть добавить в основную таблицу своего рода флаг типо  is_archived?

Comment: Да, именно так...

Comment: Ситуация изменилась.Оказывается флаг тут не поможет,так как при отзывае лицензий я должен сохранить себе эту инфу,и отключить акк которому была выдана лицензия.Но данный ак может может сам себе купить лицензию и продолжить работу,и при этом удалить данные о своей работе,и в этом случае если будет одна общая таблица не смогу и я просматривать его статистику,так как он удалит ее.

Comment: @quaresma89 не очень понял в чем проблема. при работе с этим полем вы не удаляете данные в таблице, а только помечаете их как удаленные. "удалить данные о своей работе" - он физически же не имеет доступ к таблице...

Comment: Тут же возникает след. момент.Я как тот кто выдал лицензию решил удалить его лицензию,а так же удалить данные о нем,мне они не нужны.То есть я помечаю так же в таблице каr удаленные но физически не удаляю их.И юзер захоидт как независимый аккаунт и у него уже данные помечены как удаленные? и как он будет просматривать их!

Comment: @quaresma89 Хм. Если вам данные могут пригодится - вы их удаляете логически (флажком). Если вам данные больше не нужны совсем, то можете удалять строчку на физическом уровне. Это напоминает работу с Корзиной на рабочем столе. Всех аспектов вашей задачи я не знаю, но думаю суть ясна...

Comment: подскажите а если использовать мой вариант с отдельной таблицей,можно как то ее модифицировать каждый раз с помощью ALTER на основе запроса?

Comment: Стандартных средств нет, но всегда можно написать самому. Думаю, лучше меня обе таблицы одновременно...